# How do i get the list of replaced files using nantcontrib vssget task in cruise control . net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant, visual-sourcesafe, nantcontrib

I am using [NantContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/) [`vssget`](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/vssget.html) task to retrieve the latest code from Source Safe in a build process. I would like to know what files have been updated /replaced, basically any changes that have occurred, and output it to screen/log file.

The only output I get is...

```
[vssget] Getting '$/project' to 'C:project'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the verbose attribute as follows:

```
<vssget
 user="myusername"
 password="mypassword"
 localpath="C:\project"
 recursive="true"
 replace="true"
 writable="true"
 dbpath="C:\VSS\srcsafe.ini"
 path="$/project"
 verbose="true"
/>
```